# How can i setup a page in Joomla, so only when users pay, they get to view it

Tags: joomla, permissions, payment

Topic says it all... How can i setup a page in Joomla, so only when users pay, they get to view it.

Comment: you should look at the Joomla Extensions Directory before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Akeeba Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/19528). This will allow you to make people pay to join a joomla user group. You then assign the article so that only people in that user group can see it

Answer (score 2):

OSE Membership Control and PayPlans are two other very good Joomla extensions that allow you to set up a subscription membership site where only paying members can access certain content.

Answer (score -1):

My way of achieving it, is configuring these articles to have "Access Level = registered" (when access level is "public" the article is viewable by all users!), see the following screenshot from the "Article manager" screen:

[image]

When the user pays - I generate new credentials (programatically) which he/she can use in order to access the "member's area" (you have to enable "mod_login" under the "Module manager" section for that).